# How to start a screen session from a shell script using crontab and then reattach to it?

Tags: ubuntu, shell, cron, crontab

I want to run the following shell script (launch.sh) to start/stop a screen session using crontab

```
!/bin/bash

cd ~/screen

DATE_FORMAT=+%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S

echo --- START ---
date $DATE_FORMAT

if [ -f ./screen.pid ]
then
  PID="$(cat ./screen.pid)"
  echo Stopping mitmproxy screen PID=$PID
  kill $PID
  rm ./screen.pid
fi

echo Rotating log files
logrotate -s ./logrotate.status ./logrotate.config

#Starting proxy in reverse mode
screen -S tty-mitmproxy -d -m mitmproxy -p 3333 -R http://localhost:8000 -a ./mitmproxy.log

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  PID="$(screen -ls | awk '/\.tty-mitmproxy\t/ {print strtonum($1)}')"
  echo Starting mitmproxy screen PID=$PID
  echo $PID > ./screen.pid
fi

date $DATE_FORMAT
echo --- END ---

exit 0
```

If I run it manually through a bash terminal

```
/home/fernando/screen/launch.sh >> /home/fernando/screen/launch.log 2>&1
```

It works as expected

```
cat /home/fernando/screen/launch.log
```

Output (after executed twice)

```
--- START ---
2016-05-10:22:50:32
Rotating log files
Starting mitmproxy screen PID=4897
2016-05-10:22:50:32
--- END ---
--- START ---
2016-05-10:22:50:34
Stopping mitmproxy screen PID=4897
Rotating log files
Starting mitmproxy screen PID=4919
2016-05-10:22:50:34
--- END ---
```

In this case, I can reattach to my screen session normally through a bash terminal

```
screen -r
```

I would like to do the same, but executing the above shell script via crontab

So, I added the following line to my user's crontab

```
*/10 * * * * /home/fernando/screen/launch.sh >> /home/fernando/screen/launch.log 2>&1
```

After the scheduled time, I tried to reattach as before through a bash terminal

```
screen -r
```

This time, I got the response

```
There is no screen to be resumed.
```

Checking my log file I found this weird output (after executed twice by crontab)

```
--- START ---
2016-05-10:23:00:01
Rotating log files
Starting mitmproxy screen PID=
2016-05-10:23:00:02
--- END ---
--- START ---
2016-05-10:23:10:01
Stopping mitmproxy screen PID=
kill: uso: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... ou kill -l [sigspec]
Rotating log files
Starting mitmproxy screen PID=
2016-05-10:23:10:01
--- END ---
```

I've searched syslog too

```
grep "launch.sh" /var/log/syslog
May 10 23:00:01 fernando-PC CRON[4992]: (fernando) CMD (/home/fernando/screen/launch.sh >> /home/fernando/screen/launch.log 2>&1)
May 10 23:10:01 fernando-PC CRON[5045]: (fernando) CMD (/home/fernando/screen/launch.sh >> /home/fernando/screen/launch.log 2>&1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS.: I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and my screen version is 4.01.00devel (GNU) 2-May-06

**EDIT:**

The problem seems to be related with the following line of my shell script

```
screen -S tty-mitmproxy -d -m mitmproxy -p 3333 -R http://localhost:8000 -a ./mitmproxy.log
```

If I change the command executed inside the screen section this way

```
screen -S tty-top -d -m top
```

It works!

Comment: Did you use `crontab -e` as your user to add the screen job? It worked as expected for me on Linux Mint. Any error messages in `cron` related log files? The relevant line in my `syslog`: `/var/log/syslog:May 10 10:35:01 fooHost CRON[3911]: (fooUser) CMD (/usr/bin/screen -d -m top)`

Comment: @waywardone You're right. It works fine. However, I have described here a simplification of my original problem. In reality, I'm executing screen from a shell script. I'll change my question and add more details.

Comment: Would be better to post this question to Unix & Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem is that `$PID` is not defined. Both your "Starting mitmproxy screen PID" and "Stopping mitmproxy screen PID" messages don't have a PID defined. The error from `kill` doesn't appear the first time `launch.sh` is executed from cron because the PID file doesn't exist and the "Stopping mitmproxy" section doesn't execute. The second time around, `kill` is called with an undefined `$PID` and hence the error.

Does cron know where your `screen` and `awk` are? Do you need to use absolute paths in the section where you determine the PID?

Comment: I changed my script to provide the full path location for both of them, but results remain the same.

Comment: I did another test too. When I change mitmproxy for top, for example, my script is executed as expected by CRON. Therefore, I think mitmproxy is not being started correctly or is crashing right after being started. This would explain why awk is being unable to find its PID.

Comment: `mitmproxy` likely relies on something in your environment that cron doesn't have.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the call to screen with expect.  It looks like the only difference between crontab run and terminal run is that you don't have a pty when you run from crontab.  expect can emulate a pty.